# Restivus return HTML template?

Tags: meteor, restivus

I'm trying to make an api for my METEOR application.
I looked at https://atmospherejs.com/simple/rest and https://atmospherejs.com/xcv58/collection-api but that didn't work.
Now i'm on restivus : https://atmospherejs.com/nimble/restivus

The problem that i got is that when i'm trying to call the api, it always return my HTML template, otherwise i need a json response...

This is my code for the api =>

In server.js :

```
// Global API configuration
    var Api = new Restivus({
        apiPath: 'api/',
        auth: {
          token: 'auth.apiKey',
          user: function () {
            return {
              userId: this.request.headers['user-id'],
              token: this.request.headers['login-token']
            };
          }
        },
        defaultHeaders: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        onLoggedIn: function () {
          console.log(this.user.username + ' (' + this.userId + ') logged in');
        },
        onLoggedOut: function () {
          console.log(this.user.username + ' (' + this.userId + ') logged out');
        },
        prettyJson: true,
        useDefaultAuth: true,
        version: 'v1'
    });

    Api.addCollection('coupons');
```

When i try to do curl on http://localhost:3000/api/v1/login/ with some username and password data, it return me all my html template...

Someone know the solution or already have this problem ?

Thanks for your future answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the set of API options that the docs warn against using. Check the comment directly above the code [here](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus#coffeescript-1). If you want to copy and paste some code to get started, you can use the [code from the quick start example](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus#javascript). All you need is the following to get the API you're looking for:

```
var Api = new Restivus({
  useDefaultAuth: true,
  version: v1
});

Api.addCollection('coupons');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set this header: Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
in your request